# QML FolderListModel nameFilters

Tags: qml

Добавляю поиск по ListView FolderListModel. По не понятной причине если опция showDirs: true, nameFilters: ["*.*"] не работает. Хотя по логике должны отображаться только директории в которых есть совпадения с введенными значениями в searchText

```
ListView {

    id: dirView
    model: folderDirModel
    delegate: folderDeligate

    FolderListModel {
        id: folderDirModel
        sortField: FolderListModel.Name
        showDirs: true
        showFiles: false
        folder: "file:///Users/Directory"
        nameFilters: ["*.*"]
    }
```

Скрипт

```
function updateFilter()
{
    var text = searchField.text
    var filter = "*"
    for(var i = 0; i<text.length; i++)
        filter+= text[i]
        filter+="*"
    folderDirModel.nameFilters = [filter]
}

TextField{
    id: searchField
    onTextChanged: updateFilter()
}
```

Если же showFiles: true, showDirs: false. nameFilters срабатывает.

Comment: Может кто то тоже озадачен этим делом. В общем не поддерживается фильтр для директорий, так говорит документация

Answer (score 0):

В документации к **FolderListModel** для свойства **nameFilters** указано:

> Directories are not excluded by filters